# How to count observations matching the values of a vector of characters

Tags: r, vector, character, stringr, counting

I have a `dataframe` with numerous observations and different type of variables. Here's a sample of my `dataframe`:

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = 1:16, Product = c("Pizza", "Cleaning Product", 
"Chocolate", "Fruit", "Red Meat", "Cleaning Product", "Bracelet", 
"Trucker Hat", "Shirt", "Shirt", "Chicken Breast", "Chocolate", 
"Cereal", "Fruit", "Cleaning Product", "Trucker Hat"), price = c(2, 
3.5, 1, 1, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 5, 15, 20, 2.5, 1, 2, 1, 3.5, 4), place = c("Supermarket", 
"Supermarket", "Supermarket", "Little Store", "Supermarket", 
"Supermarket", "Little Store", "Gas Station", "Supermarket", 
"Supermarket", "Little Store", "Gas Station", "Gas Station", 
"Little Store", "Supermarket", "Supermarket")), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

| # of observation | Product | Price in $ | Place |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pizza | 2 | Supermarket |
| 2 | Cleaning Product | 3.5 | Supermarket |
| 3 | Chocolate | 1 | Supermarket |
| 4 | Fruit | 1 | Little Store |
| 5 | Red Meat | 2.5 | Supermarket |
| 6 | Cleaning Product | 3.5 | Supermarket |
| 7 | Bracelet | 3 | Little Store |
| 8 | Trucker Hat | 5 | Gas Station |
| 9 | Shirt | 15 | Supermarket |
| 10 | Shirt | 20 | Supermarket |
| 11 | Chicken Breast | 2.5 | Little Store |
| 12 | Chocolate | 1 | Gas Station |
| 13 | Cereal | 2 | Gas Station |
| 14 | Fruit | 1 | Little Store |
| 15 | Cleaning Product | 3.5 | Supermarket |
| 16 | Trucker Hat | 4 | Supermarket |

I also have a `vector` of `characters`:

```
non.food <- c("Cleaning", "Hat", "Shirt", "Bracelet")
```

I have to eliminate observations that match any of the words from the `vector` `non.food`. For this I use the following code:

```
non.food <- paste(c("Cleaning", "Hat", "Shirt", "Bracelet"), collapse = '|') 
mydf <- mydf %>% 
filter(!str_detect(Product,non.food))
```

It works pretty well but I have the impression that I lose more observations than I should. For instance, looking at the sample I should lose 8 observations. But in reality I end up losing 10 (I don't show it in the sample since in reality I have 8916 observations, so the sample is just an example of what kind of dataframe I face)

So, I would like to first count the number of observations that match any of the words inside the `vector` to be sure that my `code` didn't eliminate more observations than it should. I cannot use commands as `which(mydf$Product == non.food)` or `sum(mydf$Product == non.food)`. I could do the inverse of my code and filter only by observations that match my strings of characters to verify, but it takes more time and creates more `data` that I don't want. Does anybody has an idea?

Also, **if** my `code` is in fact eliminating more observations than it should, does somebody has a solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555591/how-to-use-str-detect-within-across-when-searching-multiple-columns-for-several

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count matching or non-matching elements, you can use

```
num_foods <- nrow(mydf[!str_detect(mydf$Product, non.food),])
num_non_foods <- nrow(mydf[str_detect(mydf$Product, non.food),])
```

You can see, that `num_foods == 8` and `num_non_foods == 8`, so your code seems to do what it should.

data

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = 1:16, Product = c("Pizza", "Cleaning Product", 
"Chocolate", "Fruit", "Red Meat", "Cleaning Product", "Bracelet", 
"Trucker Hat", "Shirt", "Shirt", "Chicken Breast", "Chocolate", 
"Cereal", "Fruit", "Cleaning Product", "Trucker Hat"), price = c(2, 
3.5, 1, 1, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 5, 15, 20, 2.5, 1, 2, 1, 3.5, 4), place = c("Supermarket", 
"Supermarket", "Supermarket", "Little Store", "Supermarket", 
"Supermarket", "Little Store", "Gas Station", "Supermarket", 
"Supermarket", "Little Store", "Gas Station", "Gas Station", 
"Little Store", "Supermarket", "Supermarket")), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It works for the counting issue! The problem now is that it counts more observations than it should. Probably there is something wrong with my vector.

Comment: try `mydf[!str_detect(mydf$Product, non.food),]` or `mydf[str_detect(mydf$Product, non.food),]` to figure out what counts as foods or non-foods. You will most likely need to find an example of a mismatched element to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Yes! I already did it but everything seems fine, there are not mismatched elements. Yet, ```nrow(mydf[str_detect(mydf$Product, non.food),])``` returns 2060 elements while ```mydf[str_detect(mydf$Product, non.food),]``` shows the correct number which is 369. I double checked names too

Comment: Sounds weird! You should try to post some data where this issue is replicated to get any more help from SO

Answer (score 1):

You could add a count variable, that counts the number of deleted rows using `case_when`, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
    df <- tribble(
      ~"# of observation", ~Product, ~"Price in $", ~Place,
      1, "Pizza", 2, "Supermarket",
      2, "Cleaning Product", 3.5, "Supermarket",
      3, "Chocolate", 1, "Supermarket",
      4, "Fruit", 1, "Little Store",
      5, "Red Meat", 2.5, "Supermarket",
      6, "Cleaning Product", 3.5, "Supermarket",
      7, "Bracelet", 3, "Little Store",
      8, "Trucker Hat", 5, "Gas Station",
      9, "Shirt", 15, "Supermarket",
      10, "Shirt", 20, "Supermarket",
      11, "Chicken Breast", 2.5, "Little Store",
      12, "Chocolate", 1, "Gas Station",
      13, "Cereal", 2, "Gas Station",
      14, "Fruit", 1, "Little Store",
      15, "Cleaning Product", 3.5, "Supermarket",
      16, "Trucker Hat", 4, "Supermarket"
    )
    
    
    
    non.food <- paste(c("Cleaning", "Hat", "Shirt", "Bracelet"), collapse = "|")
    mydf <- df %>%
      mutate(count = case_when(
        str_detect(Product, non.food) ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ 0
      )) %>%
      mutate(sum_deleted = sum(count)) %>% 
      filter(!str_detect(Product, non.food))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is in fact useful but is not exactly what I'm looking for. I try to look for a "pre-step" before deleting the rows. I also can use the Environment panel in R to look how many observations where lost after running the code. The problem is that I lose more observations than I should, so i want to check how many I should lose before deleting them